# Does Rcpp enables C++ datatypes such as int, std::string etc. as input or output parameters?

Tags: rcpp

I was trying something like below (A rough example):

**test.cpp:**

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
#include <string>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RcppExport int R_load_lib(SEXP R_strDllPath);

int R_load_lib(SEXP R_strDllPath)
{
   int nStatus; 
   std::string strDllPath = Rcpp::as<std::string>(R_strDllPath);
   nStatus = LoadLibrary(strDllPath.c_str());

  Rcpp::Rcout << "LoadLib status is " << nStatus << "\n";//This get printed and then crash happens

   return nStatus;
}
```

**Compilation steps for C++ code (Using cygwin):**

```
g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++  -L$(R_HOME)/bin/x64 -lR
-L$(R_HOME)/library/Rcpp/libs/x64 -lRcpp -fPIC -shared test.o -o test.dll
```

**test.R:**

```
dyn.load("test.dll")
status<-.Call("R_load_lib", "D:/R_test/sample.dll")
```

Comment: We'd need a crash stacktrace and the code calling at least to guess what's crashing.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your code does not compile, since `LoadLib` and `Rcpp::cout` are unknown. As for the question in the subject: Yes, that is possible. You could use a signature `int R_load_lib(std::string strDllPath)`. At the very least you should read the [Rcpp introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) vignette.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Ralf Stubner. As suggested, I have added the complete code along with c++ code compilation steps. Also I have gone through that documentation earlier as well but found it less useful for solving the crash.

Comment: @RalfStubner: How about removing the downvote? Thanks.

Comment: @sourabhkesharwani not my downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out the answer to my question. I have gone through http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-introduction.pdf. In this pdf some examples are there that shows how we should use SEXP for in or out from C/C++ to R. I have tried the same and it is working fine now without a crash. So my C++ code now look like:

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
#include <string>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RcppExport SEXP R_load_lib(SEXP R_strDllPath);

SEXP R_load_lib(SEXP R_strDllPath)
{
   int nStatus; 
   std::string strDllPath = Rcpp::as<std::string>(R_strDllPath);
   nStatus = LoadLibrary(strDllPath.c_str());

  Rcpp::Rcout << "LoadLib status is " << nStatus << "\n";//This get printed and then crash happens

   return Rcpp::NumericVector(nStatus);
}
```

Comment: You might want to add your working code to make this into a proper answer. Anyway, i maintain that it is possible to use `int` and `std::string` directly in the signatures of functions exported to R. Using `SEXP` is needed only in exceptional cases, but of course possible if you want to do so. BTW, with your full example I learned the `LoadLibrary` is a windows only function ...

Comment: @RalfStubner Thank you again for your comment. So you mean to say the code I have added in question should work fine, right?

Comment: It seems to be working for you. However, I cannot test your code since I am on Linux where `LoadLibrary` does not exist. Your code and method of compilation does seem more complex than necessary, though. In most cases I don't use `RcppExport` and `SEXP` directly. I also don't call the compiler or `dyn.load()` directly. All this is done by `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`.